# When I'm trying to launch Spyder from anaconda, I'm getting launch error related to PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I was troubleshooting a pyInstaller code where I was encountering pyQT5 error.I tried to reinstall it for which it said that some other Python application is using it. So I checked and closed Spyder and Anaconda using task manager, and finally reinstalled it.
But now when I am trying to open Spyder, I am getting the below issue.

```
File "C:\Users\SCHOOL\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\SCHOOL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 144, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\SCHOOL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 92, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "C:\Users\SCHOOL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```